# Disable status line in vim's Syntastic

Tags: vim, syntastic

I use syntastic plugin for vim on a computer with small screen, so want to cut out the unnecessary space. But, syntastic, when there's an error, displays e.g.:

```
[Syntax: line: 5 (1)]
a.cpp|5 col 59 warning|some error
[Location List] :SyntasticCheck gcc (cpp)
Vim status bar
```

Is is possible to remove the status line (`[Syntax: line...`) and the last line (`[Location List...`), which I don't necessarily need?
I tried disabling the loclist altogether (then I see the warnings/errors in the vim status bar), but I cannot scroll status bar, when it's too long -- but maybe it is possible?

Before turning on loclist: [image: no loclist]

After:

[image: with loclist on]

Here I have already removed the statusline formatting string from my `~\.vimrc`. I would like the loclist to occupy one extra line, now it takes 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the it's not possible to entirely solve the problem that I asked for, as the loclist is considered another vim window and as such, the first extra line is a mandatory status line of the main window. One can disable the second extra line though by passing:

```
set laststatus=0
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to hide the statusbar.

Take a look at this [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/140898/vim-hide-status-line-in-the-bottom), which implements a function to toggle that functionality.

Or, to disable it altogether:

```
set noshowmode
set noruler
set laststatus=
set noshowcmd
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The example you gave doesn't compile (laststatus need a number) and disables only one of the two extra lines.

Answer (score 0):

To disable the status bar (the top bars, not the bottom line with `format '%d' ...`)

Supposedly set `laststatus=0` should work. However I noticed this was not working in my vimrc but would work if set manually for each vim session.

To resolve this issue, I added an `autocmd` within my `.vimrc` to override any existing `laststatus` setting:

```
# ~/.vimrc

" Hide Status Line
set laststatus=0 " For some reason this doesnt work
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile * set laststatus=0 " This will work instead
```

Answer (score 0):

As Weston Ganger said, laststatus=0 may not work in the vimrc file. In my case, the reason was in the vim-airline plugin. As stated in https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=241303, in airline.vim has a line `set laststatus=2`, which just needs to be corrected to `set laststatus=0`.